# How to create an activity log file in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am required to make an application such as a kanban board. I need to create an activity log file which prints information indicating various activities like creating a card, moving a card to another column, destroying a card, etc. Are there any methods to do so or any lib to use to implement such a file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **java.util.logging** if you don't want to add any dependencies.
Popular external libraries you can use for logging: [logback](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback), **log4j** or [log4j2](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2).

If you like you can use this library as a facade for logging frameworks: [SLF4J](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j)